# Creating a class with random, multiple-value attributes

Tags: python, class, random

I'm struggling with writing my first program. Basically, there will be two objects, which will consist of, say, 5 attributes. Each attribute is then defined by two parameters, `randint(1, 6)` and `randint(1, 20)`. The program will then evaluate the relationship of each attribute of `Object1` with each attribute of `Object2`.

I am trying to create a class that would generate these two objects, but all I can come up with is this...

```
from random import randint

    class Object:
        def __init__(self):
            self.Attribute1a = randint(1,6)
            self.Attribute1b = randint(1,20)
            self.Attribute2a = randint(1,6)
```

and so on...

Also, is there a way to assign two or more parameters to each attribute, so that I can just have AttributeX, not AttributeXa and then AttributeXb?

Comment: Don't over-think this, it's a waste of time for such a small task. Just try it. This is a simple program, so it doesn't cost much to just experiment with different ideas.

Comment: If your attributes are random, don't pass them; instead, randomly assign them *in* __init() and just have the self argument

Comment: @BartoszKP, it's easy to not over-think it when you have actual ideas.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a little bit of code, not sure if this is close to what your idea was

Comment: No do 'self.attribute1a = randint(1,6)'

Comment: Thank you! Also, is there a way to assign two or more parameters to each attribute, so that I can just have AttributeX, not AttributeXa and then AttributeXb?

Comment: Use a tuple: `self.attribute_x = (randint(1,20), randint(1,6))`. You should spend a little more time going through some Python tutorials; you don't seem to have covered all the basics yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a tuple: `self.Attribute1 = (randint(w,x), randint(y,z))`
where w, x, y, and z are whatever constants you want. Then, you can compare them by accessing each column individually: `Attribute1[0]` and `Attribute1[1]`.

Here's an idea: let's try to take your first program concept and make it a little more object-oriented. While the program you describe works, I think you're more interested in practicing inter-class relationships -- correct me if I'm wrong here. How about creating two classes: `RandomObjectA` and `RandomObjectB`. In both of these classes, define a set of variables, and then compare them within your main method. This will really help you understand how programming works on an object level, which is a much more important lesson than specific data constructs.

Once you've done that successfully, I would add some methods to each of your classes; how can you make it such that classes don't directly interact with attributes in other classes?

After that, I'd look into inheritance. What if we wanted to create 100 classes called `RandomObjectX`? It obviously wouldn't be reasonable to hand-code each and every last one, so let's think about how we can derive functionality from a higher-up class, called a superclass.

Lastly, while I appreciate that you're jumping in and trying things, I highly recommend that you read the Python tutorial and documentation. It's honestly not a hard read, you'll learn a ton, and you'll have a better scope of what exactly is going on when you code. If you combine hands-on practice and personal projects with reading documents, coding becomes much easier. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I would like to clarify a couple of things, though. How is creating two separate classes which will have the exact same make-up be beneficial here? Or will RandomObjectB inherit from RandomObjectA? And what kinds of methods could be added to these separate classes?

Comment: @sivanes: Ah ha, excellent. You're absolutely correct, there is no benefit to making two classes that are exactly the same. I was operating under the assumption that you were a little bit newer to OOP, and I find that typically a good way to teach inheritance is by showing "here's two similar classes, now what's the problem with that? How can we make it better?". If you already have a good handle on that, I'd recommend just skipping to a single `RandomObject` class and have them interact between each other! Practice your OOP until you have it down really well, it's important ;)

Comment: Got it, thank you! I have made the mistake of reading Learn Python The Hard Way very passively, so some things have stuck with me, while others (sometimes even the a lot more basic ones) haven't at all.

Comment: @sivanes: LPTHW is a great tutorial, I'd highly recommend you really go over the OOP-related ones. Overall, syntax is easy but design is hard -- if you can plan out a program on paper logically, you're 90% of the way there. Being able to code a design is pretty trivial once you've been doing it for a short period of time, so that design process is where you should focus as much attention as you can towards! Good luck!